# What would be causing this VBA program to compile but do nothing? [Rotman Interactive Trader]

Tags: vba, finance

The following is my code:

```
Function newsArb(timeremaining)

    Dim API As RIT2.API
    Set API = New RIT2.API

    While timeremaining <> 0

        Do While Range(UB_Ask_Delta) > Range(UB_Dollar_Threshold)
            OrderID = API.AddOrder("UB", UB_Order_Size * UB_Ask_QualVol, 0, 1, 0)
            OrderID = API.AddOrder("GEM", (UB_Order_Size * UB_Ask_QualVol) * GEM_Ask_Ratio, 0, 1, 0)
            OrderID = API.AddOrder("ETF", (UB_Order_Size * UB_Ask_QualVol) * ETF_Bid_Ratio, 0, -1, 0)
        Loop

    Wend

End Function
```

Each range value refers to a named list in an Excel spreadsheet. I was planning to replicate the above strategy a total of six times -- for the bid and ask of three securities. However, when I save it, launch Rotman, and initialize it using newsArb within Excel, it simply does not execute. Please let me know if you see anything that would cause it to not run.

Comment: What do you mean by "not execute"? Do you get an error? Does it hang if you step through it with the debugger?

Comment: What happens when you step through the code in the debugger?

Comment: In the code sample you posted, `newsArb` is never called. How are you calling it? What is Rotman?

Comment: http://rit.rotman.utoronto.ca/ ?

Comment: How does this terminate? There is nothing I can see in the function that reduces timeremaining. And I assume the inner two loop condition ranges are formula based?

Comment: *it simply does not execute*
Please submit the steps you have taken to verify this.

Comment: Sorry all, I call newsArb() in an excel sheet with the argument timeremaining referencing the cell that pulls Rotman data for time remaining.